# Declaring and testing LOCAL variable in if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm in need to declare a local variable and test for it inside of condition of if statement. I want to be able to do it as it is possible like this, however I need to do it without global scope; is this possible?

```
notWorkingSofar('#element');
function notWorkingSofar(a) {
   if(!(b=document.getElementById(a.slice(1)))){return b;}
   else{return false;}
}
```

I need it to basically do this; however that gives SyntaxError.

```
notWorkingSofar('#element');
    function notWorkingSofar(a) {
       if(!(**var** b=document.getElementById(a.slice(1)))){return b;}
       else{return false;}
    }
```

Is there any other way to access or set local variables, other then by "var variable="? Maybe by function.variable, akin to window.variable... Not sure though.

EDIT: Trying to do it inside a chain of these: (!!(b = document.getElementById(a.slice(1)))?b:[0,])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a variable at all. You could just do:

```
function notWorkingSofar(a) {
   return document.getElementById(a.slice(1)) || false;
}
```

or if you are not going to test for strict equality, even

```
return document.getElementById(a.slice(1));
```

will be fine.

---

If you really want a local variable than declare it with

```
var b;
```

beforehand.

Comment: I would remove one `)` though.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post on an old thread. I came here through google, looking for something similar. I also wanted to declare and test a variable in the same condition for whatever reason, and was able to as follows:

```
function myfunction(){
  var myTestVar;
  if((myTestVar = testFunction($('#myInput').val())) && (myTestVar == "Value I want")){
    //Do stuff in here
  }
}
```

The first part will always evaluate as true because it is just an assignment, and then you can test the new value in the second half of the statement. Hope someone finds this helpful!

Comment: Yeh, I already have been doing this, I wanted to find a better way. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: BTW, shoot me an email @gmail.com if you like making new programmer friends. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax won't work (as you have seen).  What's wrong with:

```
function notWorkingSofar(a) {
   var b = document.getElementById(a.slice(1));
   if(!(b)){return b;}
   else{return false;}
}
```

Comment: I actually needed to write it like this: (!!(b = document.getElementById(a.slice(1)))?b:[0,])

Comment: @TERMtm: why do you need to write it on one line like that?

Comment: Wanted to do it with as few characters possible, for cleanliness sake, and the more I try doing tedious things like that, the more I learn. My code OCD has been how I self-educate most efficiently.